# How to convert powerpoint chart for web use?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, powerpoint, google-visualization

I have some PowerPoint charts I want to convert to Google Chart or Highchart equivalent. The only current way I can think about of doing this is to manually enter all the data in the plugin but this is a real painful process. Is there any API that supports this type of conversion or maybe a converter I can use to convert the powerpoint charts to web format? Thanks.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: PPT charts are just images. So you want a way to re-digitize the data into x/y values? Good luck with that. Much easier to just get what the initial data query was that created that chart and import it.

Comment: You could always export the PowerPoint / Excel chart as an image...

Comment: @Mark: I thought about that, but problem is that I want to retain all the click and hover effects provided by PowerPoint. I ended up using HighCharts, wrote a simple code to create the highchart data from the excel to the format supported by highchart. I will post what I did shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On looking for a solution, the closest I could find was HighCharts. The examples looked exactly like what I wanted and it was very easy to use and supply data for. I copied out all the charts data to notepad, and used the following code to format them for use in HighCharts:

```
        var allfiles = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
        foreach (string s in allfiles)
        {
            var line = s.Split('\t');
            var sn = string.Format("['{0}', {1}],\r\n", line[0], line[1]);
            File.AppendAllText("nfile.txt", sn);
        }
```

See [sample](http://eyapssa.org/apps/1.html).